# How to make the content of a carousel change only by clicking on the next and prev buttons?

Tags: jquery, css, html, bootstrap-4, carousel

is it possible to make the content of a carousel not change automatically? I have this code that belongs to a bootstrap 4 carousel and I wanted to make the content of the carousel only show by clicking on the prev and next buttons.
to those buttons (prev and next) can you change the icon they have and give it a name and button shape?

this is the code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="img1.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="img2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="img3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Use data-interval="false" for to stop carousel sliding
You can change that prev & next button by changing that anchor tag as you wish

Comment: yeah thank you, that's working for me. And yes, I have modified the buttons, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Use `data-interval="false"`. You can find here all the options:https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
<!--                                                                          ^^^ Add this option here -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/200/100?image=0" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/200/100?image=0" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/200/100?image=0" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That Works for me.